# how to install module cfg80211 on ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 3.16.0

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I have worked with ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.12.0-rc6, but recently I need to switch to kernel 3.16.0-generic for a project. I have full Internet access with kernel 4.12.0-rc, while these net drivers are all based on module cfg80211. This module is not included in kernel 3.16.0-generic, so I have no Internet access. However, this is the module that I need for my project. How can I install cfg80211 in kernel 3.16.0-generic or where can I get kernel 3.16.0-generic with module cfg80211 included? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where did you download 3.16? Was there an ‘extras’ package that you missed?

Comment: Thank you very much! I install 'extra' over the current 3.16.0 kernel. It is solved now!